# Is there any view or table to show how long a session have been in Idle state in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

As my question title, Is there any view or table to show how long a session have been in IDLE state in Oracle ?

So that I can monitor how long this session have been in IDLE state.

It doesn't mean how to set session expired-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `v$session` stores this information.

`v$session.LAST_CALL_ET`:

> If the session STATUS is currently ACTIVE, then the value represents
>   the elapsed time in seconds since the session has become active. If
>   the session STATUS is currently INACTIVE, then the value represents
>   the elapsed time in seconds since the session has become inactive.

[Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223).